# Okta Logout With Nuxt.js/Vue and OpenId

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, okta

I've seen a lot of people have this issue (not just with Vue), where when you try to log the user out this error is seen:

```
{
"errorCode": "invalid_client",
"errorSummary": "A client_id must be provided in the request.",
"errorLink": "invalid_client",
"errorId": "oae1R3sir06RJOLBoPOl08IUQ",
"errorCauses": []
}
```

It is extremely confusing given the fact that the Okta documentation does not say that you need to specify a client_id as a query param, instead you need to supply id_token_hint and post_logout_redirect_uri. I've tried this multiple ways, first using the built in Vue auth module:

```
this.$auth.logout();
```

This method redirects to the correct logout url, but only supplies a client_id and redirect url as query params (which doesn't match the Okta documentation here: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-users-out/vue/sign-out-of-okta/

After reviewing that documentation I setup my method like this:

```
      this.token = (this.$auth.strategy as LocalScheme).token.get() as string;
      this.token = this.token.replace('Bearer ', '');

      // Clear remote session
      window.location.href = `${
        this.$auth.ctx.$config.OAUTH_ISSUER
      }/v1/logout?id_token_hint=${
        this.token
      }&post_logout_redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
        'http://localhost:3000'
      )}`;
```

Both methods give the same exact error, at this point I can't tell if it is an issue with how the Okta App is setup, or if I'm doing something wrong when supplying the query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. I was able to run into situation like yours, when I was prepping an example for you. Initially I had one authZ server and client_id params, but I changed them to a preview environment. In the same browser I ran into the issue, which you described.

I opened a different browser and it worked for me, so maybe there is some sort of cookie issue.

The example (not Vue though) is sitting at [glitch.com](https://glitch.com/%7Efascinated-frosted-huckleberry). Have a look if you want.

Comment: I've already tried creating an incognito tab to make sure it wasn't the browser and still didn't work. Also can't seem to find the example that you are talking about on that site...

Comment: Should be in this file - https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fascinated-frosted-huckleberry?path=callback.html%3A1%3A0

Comment: Oh okay I see it now, yeah looks like you are doing something very similar, I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my token or okta app setup now. I'm assuing the vue method for getting the token returns the id token, but I'm not totally certain.

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica did you get a solution figured out using VUE? I am getting the same error and it tells me I need a client_id in the request. Thanks.